# Pulling images from a JSON array

Tags: jquery, json

I'm having an issue pulling some images out of a json array.

here is my code

```
    for (var n = 0; n < detail.photos.length; n++) {
    var photos = detail.photos[n]
    var photo_img = $("<img />", {
        "src": photos
    });
    $("#Gallery").append("<br />" + photo_img)
}
```

what this code for my imageloop is outputting is [object, OBJECT] for each image.
I tried adding an `alert(photos);` and what it does is give me an alertbox with the source for each image. I can't figure out how to get the images to display propery.

Ah the solution as pointed out below is that you can't use concatenation with .append()

Comment: Well, first, your JSON is broken -- the way you've got it right now, `photos` is a part of `Hotel`, and `details` is missing a closing brace, and `photos` has a comma where there shouldn't be one.  Also, as far as actual `JSON` goes (text-string) and not parsed JS, each key-name should be quoted, so I'm assuming you're actually dealing with a JS object that you parsed from a JSON string.  ...if `details.hotel.photos[0]` works, great.  If not, then fix the JSON you've given us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant use concatenation in append.
cuz then you will be adding string to an object which doesnt make any sence .
it should be like this

```
  for (var n = 0; n < detail.photos.length; n++) {

    var photos = detail.photos[n];
    console.log(photos);
    var photo_img = $("<img />", {
        "src": photos
    });
     $("body").append(photo_img).append('<br>');
}
```

edit :
sorry i didnt notice that detail points to the hotel object

Comment: Thank you, the `$("body").append(photo_img).append('<br>');` line fixed my issue.